# Chrome Extension - Append to page when url changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that will listen to a url change on a domain, and when the url matches a pattern, append some HTML to the DOM.

My manifest.json looks like so:

```
{
    "name": "Append to DOM",
    "description": "Testing",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://www.somedomain.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"]
}
```

and content.js looks like so:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.url == 'http://www.somedomain.com/matching-pattern') {
        var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
        myDiv.innerHTML = 'SAMPLE HTML';
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
    }
});
```

However, the listener does not fire (and the div not appended) when the url is updated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain the listener isn't firing, and the problem isn't that the URL does not match your pattern? You've used a full URL here; something as small as https could ruin the match. (Perhaps a RegEx pattern would be better)

Comment: @Andrew That is valid, however even if I take out the conditional (so on any tab url change), I do not see the div appended, which leads me to believe the listener is not firing.

Comment: Could you use `console.log("test")` or similar to check if the listener is firing? (only suggesting this in case something weird is going on to disallow appending the div)

Comment: @Andrew Good call. But doing a log before appending does not appear in the console.

Comment: Oh gosh... Well, I have no experience writing browser extensions, but from looking a few things up, I see absolutely nothing wrong with your "content.js". I'm not sure what's going on..! I'm sorry, I wish I could help more :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content scripts don't have access to `chrome.tabs`
You can use `chrome.tabs` in the background script

In order to handle change of URL in the content script the cheapest solution that always works - use `setInterval`

```
var prevURL = '';
setInterval(function() {
    if (document.location.href != prevURL) {
        // do something
        prevURL = document.location.href;
    }
}, 1000);
```